# webpack custom command on watched files change

Tags: javascript, webpack, middleman

I'd like to be able to run a custom command when webpack detects that my files have changed. The command is to run a middleman build command that is based on rails, and not a simple js build/include.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any application that is built on top of `fsnotify` library. From ruby world you can use [`guard`](https://github.com/guard/guard) or [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) from Javascript world.

You'd want to watch your generated files.

Whenever any of the two files changes, it will execute the command.

```
nodemon --watch webpack.config.js --watch webpack.parts.js --exec \"webpack-dev-server --env development\"
```